# How to make a ruby script execute faster?

Tags: ruby

In test.csv, I have ~25k rows. When I execute the script below, it takes a long time to run. I believe this is because when I’m iterating through all unique users (the last for loop), it’s going through every single record all over again. Is there a way to make this perform faster? Perhaps delete the row once it’s been iterated through so it doesn’t have to go through it again? Something else?

```
require 'csv'

file = "test.csv"
customers = CSV.read(file)

all_users = []

# for each unique user, put his/her path in a hash.
# check if that path exists in the hash, if it doesn't add it. if it does, increment the count for that path


# Every user record
CSV.foreach(file) do |row|
    all_users << row[0]
end

# Only unique user records
unique_users = all_users.uniq


i = 0
paths = Hash.new

for user in unique_users
    path = ""
    CSV.foreach(file) do |row|
        if row[0] == user
            path = path + row[1] + ","
        end
    end

    if paths.key?(path)
        paths[path] = paths[path] + 1
    else
        paths[path] = 1
    end

    i = i + 1
    puts i
    puts paths

end
```

Comment: Benchmark it and see where your bottlenecks actually are.

Comment: With the [Benchmark module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html).

Comment: You're doing many inefficient and/or odd things in your program.  Please describe more clearly what the problem is that you are going to solve.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain what you are trying to do with your code, but I've made a few assumption that you can review and comment on if they are wrong.  Also, as you did not provide example code, I cannot test mine easily.  An example, together with desired output, would have been helpful--would still be helpful.

I expect I've made some errors.  I would be grateful if readers would report any they spot.

Here is a way to refactor your code that should speed it a lot, as each record of the file is only read once.

**Code**

```
require 'csv'

def count_by_path(fname)
  CSV.foreach(fname).with_object({}) { |(cust, path), path_by_cust|
    (path_by_cust[cust] = (path + ",")) unless path_by_cust.key?(cust) }
      .values
      .each_with_object({}) { |path, count_by_path|
        count_by_path[path] = (count_by_path[path] || 0) + 1 }
end
```

This is called with

```
count_by_path(fname)
```

and returns a hash whose keys are paths and whose values are the number of customers who have that path.

**Explanation**

Let's go through this line by line.  First, we have:

```
CSV.foreach(fname).with_object({}) { |(cust, path), path_by_cust| ... }
```

The class method [CSV#foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) reads one array (record) from the CSV file at a time.  I'm fairly confident we can tack on [Enumerator#with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) to create an empty hash denoted by the block variable `path_by_cust`.  The first task is to build that hash.

The block variables `cust` and `path` correspond to the first two elements of each array read by `foreach`.  (Ruby will disregard any other elements in the array.)

For each record we execute:

```
(path_by_cust[cust] = (path + ",")) unless path_by_cust.key?(cust)
```

(It appear from your code that paths might be concatenated, but I could not see how that was possible given that only one record per customer was to be considered.)

After all records in the file are read, this hash will be used to count paths.

We needed the customer keys in constructing this hash, but now have no further use for them (if I am correct in my understanding that you only want a count of each path; i.e., a count of the number of customers that have a given path).  Therefore, we invoke the method [Hash#values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) on the hash, which returns the values (paths) in an array.

We may now construct the hash of interest, with keys the paths and values the numbers of customers with each path:

```
.each_with_object({}) { |path, count_by_path|
  count_by_path[path] = (count_by_path[path] || 0) + 1
```

If `count_by_path` already has a key `path` (so `count_by_path[path]` is not `nil`), the expression

```
count_by_path[path] = (count_by_path[path] || 0) + 1
```

evaluates to

```
count_by_path[path] = count_by_path[path] + 1
```

On the other hand, if `count_by_path` does not have the a key `path`, the expression evaluates to:

```
count_by_path[path] = 0 + 1
```

which is precisely what we need.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is slow is that you have an exponential growth area of your code, which is the for loop.  You are checking each line against every other line. So if you have 10 lines the for loop runs 10 times and the CSV.foreach runs 10 times => 100 times you are running the code within the CSV.foreach block.

So for 25k lines you are running this block

```
{|row| path = path + row[1] + "," if row[0] == user}
```

625,000,000 times, when it can only be run 25k times + the number of unique names.

I'm also not 100% sure what you want to do, but here is my guess.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("test.csv").with_object({}) { |(name, path), paths|
  #build the path for each user
  paths[name] = paths.fetch(name) {""} + path + ',' 
}.each_with_object({}) do |(name, full_path), counted_paths|
  #count each unique full path
  counted_paths[full_path] = counted_paths.fetch(full_path) {0} + 1
end
```

Comment: Good explanation of the problem and nice use of [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch). +1 Note you could make `fetch`'s default a second parameter rather than a block. You interpreted the question differently than I did, and you may well be right (and maybe we're both wrong). Thanks for fixing the typo in my answer.

Comment: no problem for the typo and thanks for the info on fetch, I actually forgot that it can take a second argument, which would probably look better in this case